# Crypto Encryption returns different output on every run

Tags: apex, encryption, crypto

I have the following code to encrypt a user inputted data before it is stored in Salesforce.

```
String textToEncrypt = '1111-22222-33333-44444-55555';
Blob privateKey = Blob.valueOf(Label.CONSTANT_KEY);
Blob cipherText = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES192', privateKey, Blob.valueOf(textToEncrypt));
String encodedCipherText = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(cipherText);
System.debug('Encrypted Key: ' + encodedCipherText);
```

I tested the above code in Workbench and everytime I run it, the output i.e. the encodedCipherText has a different value.

Why is this so? Both the privateKey and textToEncrypt are the static in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

encyptWithManagedIV produces a random IV each run, which is prepended to the output. Use a specific IV if you want repeatable results. Note that decryptWithManagedIV knows how to pull the IV off the front of the string, so it will always decrypt okay so long as the key is correct. See the documentation for encrypt and decrypt, which both require an IV parameter to be passed. The IV is the initialization vector used.

Comment: ohh ok. So if I pass the same encodedCipherText and privateKey to decrypt function, it will always return the correct textToEncrypt, right?

Comment: That's exactly correct. Usually, using a managed IV is less troublesome than using your own.

Comment: As sfdcfox highlighted, in encryptWithManagedIV Salesforce generates the initialization vector for you. Hence Salesforce knows about it when decrypting.